# Why does Range#select produce an Array object?

Tags: arrays, ruby, object, range, ruby-2.3

Consider I have a Range object, 
`(1..30).class # => Range`

Now consider I am trying to find the factors of `num`,

```
num = 30
factors = (1..num).select { |n| num % n == 0 }
factors.class # => Array
```

For `Ruby 2.3.1` a Range object does not have `#select`, but an Array object does. How is calling `Range#select` producing an Array object?

I believe that I am not fully understanding the Ruby Object Model. My current understanding is that `factors.class.eql? Range` should return `true`, not `false`.

`factors.class.eql? Array # => true`

Comment: The first two lines of your code works (returning `[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30]`). That means that that object `1..num`, a range, has a method `select`. You can confirm that (though there really is no need): `(1..num).methods.include?(:select) #=> true`. Where is `select` defined? There are three possibilities: in the current class, in an ancestor of that class or in an included module. We need to find the method's *owner*. First create a method object for `select`: `m = (1..num).method(:select) #=> #<Method: Range(Enumerable)#select>`. Then obtain its owner: `m.owner #=> Enumerable`...

Comment: ... We also see `Range.included_modules #=> [Enumerable, Kernel] `. So here `select` is from the included module `Enumerable`. Have a look (in my first comment) at the return value of the expression that computes `m`. You'll see that it contains `"(Enumerable)"`, which is the owner. Therefore we actually didn't have to execute `m.owner` to find `select`'s owner. The docs for the methods I've used are at [Object#method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-method) and [Method#owner](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Method.html#method-i-owner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object model in Ruby is simple, single inheritance but with ability to "mixin" modules to add shared behavior. In your case you are using the `select` method which exists in the module `Enumerable`. This module is mixed into Array, Hash, and Range. This gives instances of those classes methods such as `select`. You can read more about enumerable methods here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select

If you think about it, it makes sense that `Range#select` returns an Array. You're not selecting contiguous values from the range are you? You're selecting arbitrary values from which the block returns true, this makes it impossible to return a range therefore, `#select` will always return an array even if it's called on a Hash or any other Class that mixes in Enumerable.

**Update:**

#### To understand how Enumerable is returning an Array from a Range

To implement any classes that mix in `Enumerable` you only have to define the `#each` method on your class. Say you hypothetically re-implemented Range:

```
class Range
  include Enumerable # mixin

  def initialize(first, last)
    @number_range = first.upto last # this is an array of ints
  end

  def each(&block) # this methods returns an enumerable
    @number_range.each &block
  end
end
```

With the above we can initialize our hypothetical range instance:

```
@hypo_range = Range.new 1, 10
```

And call enumerable methods on it:

```
@hypo_range.any? { |i| i == 5 } # => true
@hypo_range.select &:odd? # => [1,3,5,7,9]
```

Because you need only implement `#each` to hook into the Enumerable API, Ruby knows exactly what to do with it no matter what the class of the object is. This is because in your new `#each` method you are iterating over an array already! Enumerable uses your `each` method under the hood to implement all the other enumerable methods on top e.g. `any?`, `select`, `find`, etc.

That `#each` method is where you tell Ruby how to iterate over your collection of objects. Once Ruby knows how to iterate over your objects the results are already an Array.

#### Rubinius implementation of Range

You can see here that Range is implemented by using `while` to loop from the `first` value until it reaches the `last` value and `yield`ing to the block on each iteration. The block collects the results into an Array and that's how you get the Array out of calling `Range#select` because `select` is using that `each` under the hood.

https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/range.rb#L118

Some resources:

- https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-ruby-collections-iii-enumerable-enumerator/
- https://mauricio.github.io/2015/01/12/implementing-enumerable-in-ruby.html
- http://practicingruby.com/articles/building-enumerable-and-enumerator

Comment: Okay, so that initially makes sense. `#select` is returning a list not conforming to a `Range` object. But How does the Ruby Object Model dictate that the evaluation of `factors` IS in fact an Array if it started off as a Range? This was a perfect example to begin understanding `mixins` nicely. But I'm not sure how Ruby doesn't break because I am still working on a Range object. So my question: How does using `Range#select` return an Array if Enumerable methods are mixed in/moduled into Range? To me it seems like it'd still return a Range. @Ursus feel free to comment.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks @diego.greyrobot. I love to use Ruby, but it's very intricate. I suppose that's why Matz said something along the lines of, 'Ruby appears simple, but is rather complex, just like our human bodies.'

Comment: I find it quite cuddly as well :)

Comment: It should be noted that, while the `Enumerable` module is included in the classes `Array`, `Hash` and `Range` (and others), [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) (which returns an array, or an enumerator) is not executed on arrays or hashes...

Comment: ...In the case of arrays, [Array#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-select) (which returns the same array as `Enumerable#select`) is executed. It is provided because it is more efficient than the more general `Enumerable#select`. For hashes, [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-select), which returns a hash, rather than an array, is executed.

Comment: Thank you @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 1):

Check the docs for Range http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Range.html

It says included modules `Enumerable`. And that's where there are implemented `map`, `all?`, `any?`, `find`, `select`, `inject` and many many more methods.